# How type URLSearchParams in typescript to receive an object?

Tags: typescript, types, urlsearchparams

I have a function that receive via param an object and this object goes inside the URLSearchParams, after this, I make a toString() and get the answer below:

```
const object = {
    name: 'Test',
    age: 20
};

function exampleFunction(objectExample) {

   const url = new URLSearchParams(objectExample);
   return url.toString();
};

console.log(exampleFunction(object));
// result: name=Test&age=20
```

The answer result is what i expected, the problem is when I tried to type this param creating an interface, like:

```
interface ObjectTest { name: string, age: number }

 function exampleFunction(objectExample: ObjectTest) {
    
       const url = new URLSearchParams(objectExample: ObjectTest) << /* error, URLSearchParams expect a type Record<string, string> */;
       return url.toString();
    };
```

Whitout typing, the code works fine,my question is: how can I type this params to receive an object if my URLSearchParams expect other thing?
I already try pass an object stringfy (like JSON.stringfy(object), but the result is something like // %7B%22ma,e%22%3A%22Test%22%2C%22age%age%22#A@)%70= instead of name=Test&age=20 )

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`URLSearchParams` takes an object as an argument, but all the values of the object have to be strings.

[`Record`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#recordkeys-type) is a utility type. `Record<string, string>` is a type given for an object whose keys and values are strings.

So you can convert the `age` to a string to fix the error:

```
interface ObjectTest { name: string, age: number }

function exampleFunction(objectExample: ObjectTest) {
    const url = new URLSearchParams({...objectExample, age: objectExample.age.toString()})
    return url.toString();
};
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgPICMBWEFgCoQDOYyA3siHALYQBcyxUoA5gDTJzN0UCuV60ZAF8AUCJg8QuYAHsQyCAA9qABwA2EAGKTpcgBQysOMAFFlVddwzZcBYgEoyI5C%20QI5xZDyhrkAXgoIAHdkAFUAJQAZAGUIOCgEAAsABXjqQj1SADocwxtTc0t2Tm484zNVDSySrLAZaLAmEGY9eyF7Z1coCDBveW81WvrGllaAbhEhMaA)